# Derivative of unit step function

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

The ramp function is given by 
r(t)=tu(t)
If we differentiate ramp ,we get unit step function. That is,
u(t)=1
So the derivative of unit step function is definitely 0 since u(t) is constant over the positive t axis.
But its derivative is actually del(t)
How is this possible?
Please explain this

Comment: Where is the mystery? To use your (horrible) notations, note that del(t)=0 for every t>0 and u(t)=1 for every t>0 and u'(t)=0 for every t>0.

Comment: @Did What does that horrible mean?

Comment: Here we go... u(t) : undefined. del(t) : undefined, nonstandard notation. u(t)=1 : wrong, u(t)=1 only if t>0...

Answer (score 1):

There is a steep and abrupt increase in the amplitude of the unit step function $u(t)$ at $t=0$, so the slope or the derivative of $u(t)$ will have a infinite slope at $t=0$ hence the derivative peaks at $t=0$ therefore it is a delta function

Comment: Somebody should mention that these are *intuitions* about the object of study but certainly not a *mathematical* description.